# Can only connect once to wireless network on Kubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu, network-manager

After upgrading from Kubuntu 15.04 to 15.10, my wireless network adaptor cannot connect to a known network. Instead of auto connecting to known networks or at least connecting when I press 'connect' in the KDE network widget I now have to remove the known network and readd it. At that point it connects normally (at work or when tethering with my phone, but not at home where it does not want to connect at all anymore). If I want to reconnect to the network I have to repeat the same steps (delete and readd).

Does anyone have that same issue? What could be the cause/solution?

Update:

When I click 'Configure network connections...' and then try to edit an existing connection the network configuration manager window disappears instantly.

I created [ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plasma-nm/+bug/1509140) and [kde](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=355067) bug reports.

Comment: Am I really the only one with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I get the same on Kubuntu 15.10.

In addition if I try to modify the connection using network manager 'Connection Editor', 'Connection Editor' simply closes as soon as I click 'Edit'.

Using the gtk-based 'nm-applet' works without any issue. This is def a kde network manager issue.

Comment: Would you mind indicating on the linked bug report that it affects you too?

Comment: Done - any idea how to run the plasma-nm in the foreground so you see some output?

Comment: Thanks! Good question, don't know... hopefully someone can make a suggestion!